# How to check if there is database server health check before sending a get Request in java?

Tags: java, node.js

I want to do a health check for the server before i send a get request to my DB server. Is there a way to achieve this so that i know the connection to the database server is working fine. My code is in Java, where i call the server and i use the node server to connect to my PostgreSQL database. I want to do the health check from my java code. I have tried a no response exception, but i found the healthcheck for the server is a good idea to implement in the code.  How can i do that ? Please help. Thanks

Comment: just execute a SQL statement and if it is successful, the server works.

Comment: What's the point of making a request to find out whether the node server can talk to the DB, and then making anther request to the node server to actually do it? How will the behaviour of your Java server change between failures of the first and second request?

Comment: this is one of the requirement of my project, just to make sure its connecting,

Comment: What exact problem are you having doing this?

Comment: Just to make sure the server is up and running.